# Npm error "Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '../node-sass/build'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Can't install the node-sass package via npm `sudo npm i`, i have been trying to resolve via `sudo npm i -g node-sass --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root` but it doesn't effect. Chmod 777 either.
I think there are something with npm permissions but i do not know
Log:

```
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/michael/Desktop/react/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/michael/Desktop/react/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/michael/Desktop/react/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/michael/Desktop/react/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v11.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/michael/.npm/_logs/2019-04-13T17_21_20_424Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As a general recommendation, never run npm install with sudo as it will create local files owned by root instead of your user, i think you shoud try the following :

- First change the owner of the folder :  `chown -R yourusername:yourusername /home/michael/Desktop/react/` , or if you don't want to type your username : `chown -R $USER:$USER /home/michael/Desktop/react/`
- then run : `npm install node-sass`, do not use sudo

**NOTE** : This is fine when you install local packages, but for global installations, read the update below

---

### **UPDATE**

**Never Run `sudo npm install`  and `sudo npm anything`** read this [article](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92) to get an idea why

**While** changing the permissions by using `chown` or `chmod` is kinda fine and works, however it isn't the best approach when installing packages **globally**, if you are on a Linux or OSX i would suggest you read this article on the npm docs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally), and either **use `nvm`**, or manually change npm's default directory.

**Changing npm's default directory**

To do so, you need to follow these steps :

1. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   ```
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   ```
   npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
   ```
3. In your preferred text editor, open or create a `~/.profile` file   [alternatively you can edit either the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file instead of `.profile` if you see fit] and add this line  :

   ```
   export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. On the command line, update your system variables:

   ```
   source ~/.profile  

   # or source ~/.bashrc,
   # source ~/.zshrc, depends on where you exported the path
   ```
5. To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

   ```
   npm install -g jshint
   ```

You can install node-sass globally :

```
    npm install -g node-sass
```

**Now** you shoudn't get permissions errors as this should resolve the EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally .

---

### **Warning**

`LibSass` and `node-sass` are deprecated. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features, projects that still use it should move onto Dart Sass.
You can read more on this topic [here](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated)

Please use sass instead, migrating to Dart Sass is straightforward
And both packages expose the same JavaScript API, to install dart sass :

```
  npm install sass
```

Or globally :

```
  npm install -g sass
```

Comment: no , next time just use :  npm install node-sass instead of using :  sudo npm install node-sass , the bash command above just fix the EACCESS errno 1 caused when you used sudo npm -i node-sass

Comment: Hi. I faced with the problem, i installed globally node-sass, and when i needed in sass it just gives a error like To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass. Therefore, it needs to install node-sass every time i use sass ? or there is the way to prevent?

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: If you are getting `illegal group name` issue then just do `sudo chown -R <username>: /location`

Comment: Remember to put space after `<username>: ` ^

Comment: Thank you. I was already getting frustrated with this issue..

Comment: I updated the answer on how to fix the error when you wanna  install packages globally..sorry i didn't read the comment section for a while

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions as per @WaLid LamRaoui's answer as I also use to run npm install with sudo. It seemed to have done the trick in terms of changing the owner of the folder, but I still got an error when trying to run `npm install`. I then realized another problem which has to do with my cache folder which contains root-owned files, so for those whose also have this problem after following the approved answer, I simply did this:

```
sudo chown -R 1003:1003 "/home/<username>/.npm"
```

After this I ran `npm install` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do nothing ..
simply add `--unsafe-perm` to it

Give it unsafe permission access.

So, let's say.. if you were previously installing bcrypt library

```
sudo npm install --save bcrypt
```

then now write

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm --save bcrypt
```

And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by running

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass
```