# Can't install node-sass inside angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, sass, node-sass

I've cloned a repo from an existing Angular project and executed **sudo npm install** within the project.

All packages were installed so far, but the packet **node-sass** still causes problems.

After the installation process of **sudo npm install** is finished I get the following error message:

> gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, mkdir '/ Users / oek1wa3 / Documents / CODEHAN / management /
>   node_modules / node-sass / build' gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0 gyp
>   ERR! command "/ usr / local / bin / node"
>   "/Users/oek1wa3/Documents/CODEHAN/management/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext = "" --libsass_cflags = ""
>   --libsass_ldflags = "" --libsass_library = " gyp ERR! cwd / Users / oek1wa3 / Documents / CODEHAN / management / node_modules / node-sass
>   gyp ERR! node -v v11.10.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok

If I try to compile the project also an error appears and displays this message (only a section):

> ```
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 749: 10)
> at Module.load (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 630: 32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 570: 12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 562: 3)
> at Module.require (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 667: 17)
> at require (internal / modules / cjs / helpers.js: 20: 18)
> at Object. <anonymous> (/Users/oek1wa3/Documents/CODEHAN/management/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
> at Module._compile (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 738: 30) ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
> ```

I've already tried to delete the **node_modules** folder and the **package-lock.json** file and run the installation again. Unfortunately without success. I could not find anything else on the net that fixed this problem.

The package.json contains the following versions of relevant packages:

```
"node-sass": "^4.7.2",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
"@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
"@angular/core": "7.2.0",
```

**My current npm version:** 6.7.0 |
**My current node version:** v11.10.0

I'm using a MacBook Pro with macOS Mojave version 10.14.5.

How can I fix this problem for my project to compiled again?

Comment: Use `npm install node-sass` without sudo and before run that command change the owner of the folder. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55668065/npm-error-error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir-node-sass-build)

Comment: @DenukaNirmalee I changed the read and write permissions of the project folder and then ran npm install. The installation went smoothly, but I still had to do a node-sass rebuild. Now everything works;)

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

It worked for me

Also Check [this](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#cannot-find-module-rootinstalljs)